# How to fix 8080 port unavailable error for parse-server in openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, parse-server

I am migrating my data back-end to openshift from parse.com.
**Step 1**. I changed openshift port binding of project into following

```
//var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
 var port = parseInt(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT) || 8080;
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

and folked as my new repo https://github.com/kyawzinsoe/parse-server-example.git

Step 2. 
Then I create a gear with my parse-server repo with following command.
    rhc app-create myserver nodejs-0.10 mongodb-2 --from-code=https://github.com/kyawzinsoe/parse-server-example.git
But it show 8080 port problem as following
[image]

What am I missing? Please help me.

Comment: I'd recommend [specifying the IP](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-environment-variables.html#listen) as well. If that does not help, try [checking the logs](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html).

Comment: try to tail the ./app-root/logs/nodejs.log, there might be exception being thrown, in my case, it is the appId and masterKey from parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is solved by @Jiri Fiala's comment that I need to set openshift IP

Answer (score 3):

You need use Node 4.1+ with parse server. OpenShift is running 0.10.x

You can use this repo https://github.com/h4t0n/nodejs-4-lts-openshift in order to run Node 4.1+ on your OpenShift app.

Comment: However you it will fail too because you need newer gcc in order to compile bcrypt native module. On openshift you have 4.4.7 :(

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

I have set up a deploy to OpenShift button that will do most of the work for you:

[image: Deploy parse-server to OpenShift]

you will still need to set up you "appId" and "masterKey" either by editing index.js file or with `rhc env set APP_ID=myAppId MASTER_KEY=myMasterKey -a myAppName`

#### This is how you can do it the same thing with `rhc` tool:

```
rhc app create parseaio http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-mongodb --from-code https://github.com/antt001/parse-server-example --env APP_ID=myAppId MASTER_KEY=myMasterKey
```

[for more in-depth instructions, check out my blog post on this topic](http://www.anttdev.com/2016/02/how-to-install-your-own-parse-server-on-openshift/)

#### Original answer

1. create app using cartridge from http://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs
   paste url from Github page into "Code Anything" textbox at the bottom of the page of application creation Choose a type of application page.
2. on next page paste https://github.com/antt001/parse-server-example into Source Code textbox, to grab parse example project, modified for openshift settings
3. add recent MongoDB cartridge as instructed at http://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-mongodb
4. clone your repo from OpenShift
5. replace "appId" and "masterKey" values in the index.js file with your app id and key.

It works fine, I am running this configuration right now.

#### Update 2

I have removed the snippet, since it is now on a GitHub repo that I mentioned above.

#### P.S.

as mentioned by @radzio, there is a problem with compiling native nodejs that requires GCC 4.8, however, this configuration does not need any of this and works as is, it uses bcrypt-nodejs instead of native

Thanks to @ionut-cristian-florescu for custom cartriges